# jquery add / remove item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a checkboxs 3-4 of them, when the user checks the checkbox I want to add the value of the checkbox to the array, if they uncheck the box I want to remove the item from the array, this is what I got so far:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {

        if ($(this).attr("id") == 'price') {
            if (this.checked) {
                priceArray.push($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                priceArray = jQuery.grep(priceArray, function (value) {
                    return value != $(this).val();
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Adding the value to the array works perfectly, however removing items results in this error:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

on this line:

```
return value != $(this).val();
```

Comment: Provide whole code.

Comment: whole code provided

Comment: Where's html code?

Comment: Without the code resulting in error, what that means is the left operand being undefined and cannot have `toLowerCase` applied to it. Please provide this code, otherwise this is pure speculation at best.

Comment: why don't you just loop over the checkboxes and get the checked ones each time instead of adding/removing with loops.

Answer (score 4):

Run the code snippet and check

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var priceArray=[];
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                priceArray.push($(this).val());
               $("#displayarray").html("array=[" + priceArray+"]");
            }
            else {
               var index = priceArray.indexOf($(this).val());
               if (index > -1) {
                  priceArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
                $("#displayarray").html("array=[" + priceArray+"]");
            }
    });
});
  
  });
</script>
<input type="checkbox" value="box1"/>box1
<input type="checkbox" value="box2"/>box2
<input type="checkbox" value="box3"/>box3
<input type="checkbox" value="box4"/>box4
<br/>
<div id="displayarray"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
priceArray = jQuery.grep(priceArray, function (value) {
    return value != $(this).val();
});
```

By

```
val = $(this).val();
priceArray = jQuery.grep(priceArray, function (value) {
    return value != val;
});
```

Don't forget the scope where your are in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```js
var values = [];

$("input").on("change", function() 
{
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if ($this.is(":checked")) 
  {
    values.push($this.val());
  }
  else 
  {
    values = values.filter(x => x != $this.val());
  }
  
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />
```

`filter()` is a native function, I prefer using built-in function rather than 3rd party's, IMO. Also, avoid binding events within loops like this:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {
```

Use this method:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() { ...
```

This will work even if checkbox is dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very cleanly with a functional style

```
<div class="checkboxes">    
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
</div>
```

And

```
(function() {
    $(".checkboxes input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
        var x = $(".checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(a,b) {
        return parseFloat(b.value);
      }).toArray();
      console.log(x)
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I was able to overcome it in the following way :

My jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dataFilterForm").on("input", function() {
        var values = '';
        var boxes = $('input[name=vehicle]:checked');
        boxes.each(function(b){
            values = values + boxes[b].id + ', ';
        });
        $('#filterResult').text(values.substring(0, values.length-2));
    });
});
```

My HTML :

```
<form id="dataFilterForm">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Filter1" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
    <label for="Filter1">Filter1</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Filter2" name="vehicle" value="Car">
    <label for="Filter2">Filter2</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Filter3" name="vehicle" value="Boat">
    <label for="Filter3">Filter3</label><br>
</form>
<p>Result : </p>
<p id="filterResult"></p>
```