# Get checkbox value when clicking the checkbox label and add/remove its value from array

Tags: jquery, html

I already have a starting code for the adding/removing of value into array. Got from this post - [jquery add / remove item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459294/jquery-add-remove-item-from-array)

My problem is i'm using label, and the jquery code i get isn't using label. I just wanted to get the value of the checkbox or the data-product value inside the label element and add it into the array.

```js
var priceArray = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.container-box input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        priceArray.push($(this).val());
        $("#selected-products").html("array=[" + priceArray + "]");
      } else {
        var index = priceArray.indexOf($(this).val());
        if (index > -1) {
          priceArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $("#selected-products").html("array=[" + priceArray + "]");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-box">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" value="4 - 6oz Teres Majors" id="wb1">
      <label for="wb1">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="4 - 6oz Teres Majors" data-class="wb1" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb1" href="#"><img src="teresmajors.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>4 - 6oz</span>
      <span title="Teres Majors" class="description">Teres Majors</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" value="4 - 6oz Top Sirloin" id="wb2">
      <label for="wb2">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="4 - 6oz Top Sirloin" data-class="wb2" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb2" href="#"><img src="topsirloin.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>4 - 6oz</span>
      <span title="Top Sirloin" class="description">Top Sirloin</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" value="2lbs Tenderloin Tails" id="wb3">
      <label for="wb3">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="2lbs Tenderloin Tails" data-class="wb3" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb3" href="#"><img src="delicious-grilled-steak-with-seasons-370w.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>2lbs</span>
      <span title="Tenderloin Tails" class="description">Tenderloin Tails</span>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your label has a nested div, with the product key as the dataset item you want.
When the checkbox is selected, I get the label for the checkbox using jQuery. Then I cast that label to a jquery label object. This label has the text and a div as children, and I want the div child of the label. I get the div child of the label using jquery, then I look in the div's dataset for a key named product. I do this for checked an unchecked so it is outside the if statement. If I am checking the checkbox, I add the product to the array. If I am unchecking the checkbox I am removing it from the array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var priceArray = [];
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.container-box input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var lbl = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']"); //get the label with this id
                var lbel = $(lbl[0]); //cast to a jquery object
                var childdiv = lbel.context.childNodes[1]; //the div is the second child of the label
                var prdct = $(childdiv).data('product'); //get the product value from the div dataset

                if (this.checked) { 
                    priceArray.push(prdct);
                    $("#selected-products").html("array=[" + priceArray + "]");
                } else {
                    var index = priceArray.indexOf(prdct);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        priceArray.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    $("#selected-products").html("array=[" + priceArray + "]");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I played a little with your code and did the following:

- Added `<div id="selected-products"></div>` at the end of your HTML,
- Added the variable `data` in the script, to target the `data-product` in the `label div` (Note that now the `id`s of the `checkbox`es are useless),
- Enhanced the function your used, by moving the line that add the array to the html after the `if { … } else { … }`, so that it appears only once.
- ...

… Here is the snippet:

```js
var priceArray = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.container-box input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      data = $(this).parent("li").find("label div").attr("data-product");
      if (this.checked) {
        priceArray.push(data);
      } else {
        var index = priceArray.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
          priceArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      $("#selected-products").html("array=[" + priceArray + "]");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-box">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" id="wb1">
      <label for="wb1">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="4 - 6oz Teres Majors" data-class="wb1" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb1" href="#"><img src="teresmajors.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>4 - 6oz</span>
      <span title="Teres Majors" class="description">Teres Majors</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" id="wb2">
      <label for="wb2">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="4 - 6oz Top Sirloin" data-class="wb2" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb2" href="#"><img src="topsirloin.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>4 - 6oz</span>
      <span title="Top Sirloin" class="description">Top Sirloin</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="add-checkmark"></div>
      <input class="prod-checkbox" name="wagyu_beef[]" type="checkbox" id="wb3">
      <label for="wb3">
                <div class="fusion-modal-text-link" title="Click for item details" data-product="2lbs Tenderloin Tails" data-class="wb3" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fusion-modal.wb3" href="#"><img src="delicious-grilled-steak-with-seasons-370w.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail"></div>
            </label>
      <span>2lbs</span>
      <span title="Tenderloin Tails" class="description">Tenderloin Tails</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div id="selected-products"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @takit, this works great. Just what i wanted.